# php update multi rows at once

Tags: php, mysql, php-5.3

I have form with multi rows. It has select menu with ID of the row

```
<select name="TYPE[700205]">
        <option value="">not used</option>
                    <option value="1">enter</option>                
                    <option value="0">exit</option>
</select>

<select name="TYPE[700206]">
        <option value="">not used</option>
                    <option value="1">enter</option>                
                    <option value="0">exit</option>
</select>
```

PHP code:

```
$TYPE = $_POST['TYPE'];

foreach($TYPE as $key=>$value){
    // die(var_dump($TYPE));//
    //  echo "key ".$key. "value " . $value;            
    $sql= ("UPDATE NEWPER.WORK_DAYS_LOG set IN_OUT=:VALUE
            WHERE LOG_ID=:ID ");    
    $rs = $this->db->Query($sql,array('ID'=>$key,'VALUE'=>$value));
}
```

It send array to update multi rows in same time but update not working.

Comment: you need to use `loop` for the multiple update rows at the same time.

Comment: I did foreach but not working